# How to co host django app with php5 on apache2 with mod_python?

Tags: php, python, django, apache, mod-python

I have django+python+apache2+mod_python installed hosted and working on ubuntu server/ linode VPS. php5 is installed and configured. We don't have a domain name as in example.com. Just IP address. So my apache .conf file looks like this

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www

```
    <Location "/">
            SetHandler python-program
            PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
            SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
            PythonOption django.root /mysite
            PythonPath "['/var/www/djangoprojects',] + sys.path"
            PythonDebug On
    </Location>
```

I want to install vtiger so if I change my .conf file like say this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.access_log combined
    <Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This way vtiger the php based app works fine and ofcourse django app is not accessible. How do I make both co-exist in one file. i cannot use virtual host/subdomains. I can do with a diff port no thou.

Any clue guys ?

Regards
Ankur Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to test it, but this should get your Django project running at /mysite/:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.access_log combined
    <Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Location "/mysite/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
        PythonOption django.root /mysite
        PythonPath "['/var/www/djangoprojects',] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug On
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, the [preferred way to host Django apps is with mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#install-apache-and-mod-wsgi).

Comment: However I want to host django app on root and not /mysite. If I do that then /vtiger urls are also redirected to django app.

Comment: You probably can only achieve what you want with mod_wsgi then, as Apache/mod_wsgi when configured properly can give preference to static resources even when Python web application mounted at root of web site. To do that with mod_python would be much more difficult and/or impossible. If you are happy moving to mod_wsgi, then can give explanation as answer and point you to where in documentation it talks about this sort of setup.

Comment: I finally ran both using mod_python but used different ports.